Errors when copying and pasting text using gVim under Windows 11
I have a reoccurring problem when using Ctrl c and Ctrl v between two files opened in gVim Version 9.1.
When I copy a portion of text from file 1 and then paste it in file 2 I get various "extra" insertions spread through file 2 of the text I just copied. Seems to be random spots (at least I haven't noticed a pattern yet).
Has anyone else seen this or is there a workaround?
I didn't notice this under Windows 10.

Copy and paste in Vim is done via y (yank) and p (put). Do you have a special mapping for <C-c> and <C-v>?

Can you please [edit] and share the minimal configuration to reproduce the issue? As Vivian pointed out, it shouldn't work at all by default. You would need to :source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim or provide mappings of your own.

... and could you also provide samples of the extra characters? Not ^M by any chance? That might happen as a result of a botched line endings conversion.

Y and P only work in the same file! to copy and paste between files I have in the past always used the "windows" commands Ctrl-c and Ctrl-v to copy and paste blocks of text. Gvim 9.1 under widows 10 works fine. Since I have moved to windows 11 not so much. By "extra" chars I mean the text I pasted gets randomly pasted in other areas of the destination file in what seems to be random places. In can be as little a only a second insertion to several. It is very destructive to source code. I have used Vi for decades and never have I seen this before windows 11. Yes I source VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
